# Mathematical induction confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

[image]

My  confusion is on that highlighted part. What did we exactly do there?
From "so w=xy" to the end

1. That B =>* x is saying it is 0 step+ derivation to make B=>x.

I understand we do k+1 and in k we write 2|w|-1. But I don't understand why are we doing it. Can you help me visualize it a bit or understand it a bit?

Answer (score 1):

$w$ is the string you are trying to derive. Since it is not of length $1$, they must have used $A \to BC$ as the first step of the derivation, and gone on from there, eventually resulting in $w$. This means that $B$ must have been transformed into something $x$, and $C$ transformed into something $y$, such that in the end, $w$ is the concatenation of $x$ and $y$, i.e. $w=xy$

We can use the inductive hypothesis to say that transforming $B$ into $x$ takes $2 | x| - 1$ steps, and that transforming $C$ into $y$ takes $2 |y| - 1$ steps. Hence, the total number of steps is $1 + 2 | x| - 1 + 2 | y| - 1 = 1 +2(|x| + |y|) -2 = 2|w|-1$